# How to make maven download dependencies from central repo. rather than downloading from remote company repo.?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-3

So I thought of creating a spring boot project but on my company laptop. I downloaded the project from spring initializer and tried to execute on IntelliJ idea but got this error:

***"java: package org.springframework.boot does not exist"***

***"java: cannot find symbol
symbol: class SpringBootApplication"***

I ran maven clean and install cmds but still the same issue. Now I reckon this is happening bc maven is downloading dependencies from my remote company repository.

I remember saving a custom setting.xml file in .m2 folder which contains a custom repository.
So if I am right how can I make maven download from the central repo or solve this problem?

Comment: what do you mean when you say central repository?

Comment: How does your settings.xml file look like? Please try to build from plain command line ...and check the output also post error messages etc. here..

Comment: @SHIV1198 Did my post answer your question? If so, I surely would appreciate a check!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you listed your own repository in your POM or settings.xml, like so:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>

        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Doing so, without also listing Maven Central, will cause Maven to only attempt to resolve from your own repository. You must also list Maven Central, like so:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>

        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>central</id>

        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Maven checks repositories in the order they are specified. You cannot specify a repository per dependency, but you could create a new module with your dependencies and their specific repositories.